# ODBC: Arrays of parameters. how to insert null values?

Tags: sql-server, null, odbc

I use column-wise binding in odbc driver for bulk insertion like in this example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
But I want to set some values as NULL. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `SQL_NULL_DATA` for `StrLen_or_IndPtr` when you call the bind function. (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248799)

Comment: This example for unit-insertion: it's not array insertion. 
In my case there is array of values for each table field. Some values may be not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `SQL_NULL_DATA` instead of `SQL_NTS`in the length parameter for the specific value you want to update as NULL.